# Dash Update HTML without a callback

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I want to change the style of some of the html elements in dash, but I don't want to use the output callbacks. The reason is, that there are 84 different elements, I want to change and I don't want to create so many Outputs in the callback.

Here is a minimal example of what I want to do:

```
import dash
from dash import dcc, html, Input, Output, State

app = dash.Dash(__name__) 

server=app.server
app.layout = html.Div(
                children=[ html.Div("Make me red",id="thediv",
                            style={"background-color":"grey"}),
                           html.Button("make it red", id="doit")
                           ]
            )

@app.callback(Input("doit","n_clicks"))
    # One output is no Problem, also creating lots of 
    # Outputs using a list of ids would be no problem
    # But then I have to create all these variables in
    # the function definition.
    # --> Dynmical variable creation, bad idea :-(
def clickit(btn):
    # how can I make the DIV red without an output callback
    # Something like app.layout['thediv']['style']={'background-color':'red'}
    return
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Is there any way to change the properties of the Div dynamically?

Comment: You want the user to change HTML elements from the dashboard, right?

Comment: Another question, does each HTML have unique style or all 84 elements will have the same style?

Comment: Yes, the change should be triggered by user input. And yes, the 84 elements will have the same style, I want to change the css class. In this example, I used the style attribute.

Comment: The user should only style all elements at the same time, I mean he/she cannot style some of the elements, right?

Comment: Oh, all elements should be changed individually, being identified by their id

Comment: Could you please mention which type of style the user can control?

Comment: The color. In the minimal example, I could use `Output('thediv','style'`) and then in the function `return {"background-color":"red"}` but I would have to write 84 Outputs in my real-world application

Comment: You can ask the user the id and which color he/she wants with two inputs instead of 84, how?

Comment: I have other inputs, but it can be done by just entering the id in an input field. The color should just toggle from red to grey